# Global Name "msg" not defined

Tags: python-3.3

I'm currently writing a class called SMS_store().  In it, I have a method called delete. 
 Delete is simply supposed to make sure the user has given me a valid integer.  If so, it's supposed to pop an item from the list.

```
class SMS_store():
      def __init__(self):
           self.__inbox = []

def delete(self, i):
    if i >= len(self.__inbox):
         return None
    else:
         self.__inbox.pop[i]
```

Whenever I run the code in my test program, I run into two errors at my delete stage:

1)  if I type myInbox.delete(2) when there's only 2 items in the list, I get "list index out of range" and I though I was protected from that error.  myInbox.delete(3) gives me None.

2)  If I type myInbox.delete(1) when there's a valid index 1 in my list, it says global name 'msg' not defined.  I don't get why I'm seeing that error.

Here's my full class code.

```
#SMS_store class
"""
Pre-condition:  SMS_store class is instantiated in client code.
Post-condition:  SMS_store class is instantiated.
"""

class SMS_store():
    #Object instantiation
    """
    Pre-conditon:  SMS_store class is instantiated in client code.
    Post-condition:  Object creates an empty list.

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.__inbox = []

    #add_new_arrival method
    """
    Pre-condition:  Class method is handed a valid phone number of 11, 10, or 7
    digits as a string with no hyphens or letters, a string containing a time,
    and a string containing the text of a message.
    Post-condition:  Method will append a tuple containing False for an
    undread message, the phone number, the time arrived and the text of the
    message to the class created list.

    """
    def add_new_arrival(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_SMS):
        number = from_number

        #Check for valid phone number and add hyphens based on number length
        if len(number) == 11:
            number = number[0] + "-" + number[1:4] + "-" + number[4:7] + "-"\
                     + number[7:]
        elif len(number) == 7:
            number = number[:3] + "-" + number[3:]
        elif len(number) == 10:
            number = "1-" + number[:3] + "-" + number[3:6] + "-" + number[6:]
        elif number.isalpha():
            number = "Invalid number"
        else:
            number = "Invalid number"

        time = time_arrived
        text = text_of_SMS
        message = (False, number, time, text)
        self.__inbox.append(message)

    #message_count method
    """
    Post-condition:  method returns the number of tuples in class created list.
    Returns None if list is empty.

    """
    def message_count(self):
        count = len(self.__inbox)
        if count == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return count

    #get_unread_indexes method
    """
    Post-condition:  method creates an empty list,checks for any tuples with
    "False" at index 0.  If "False" is found, it appends the index for the
    tuple in the list.  Method returns list of indexes.

    """
    def get_unread_indexes(self):
        unread = []
        for message in self.__inbox:
            if message[0] == False:
                unread.append(self.__inbox.index(message))
        return unread

    #get_message method
    """
    Pre-condition:  Method is passed an integer.  
    Post-condition:  Method checks for a valid index number.  If valid, the
    method will then check if indexed tuple contains "True" or "False" at index
    0.  If True, message is returned in new tuple containing items from indexes
    1, 2, and 3.  If False, a new tuple is created containing "True"
    indicating the message is now read, plus indexes 1, 2, and 3 from the
    original called tuple.

    """
    def get_message(self, i):
        #check for valid index number
        if i >= len(self.__inbox):
            return None
        else:
            msg = self.__inbox[i]
            if msg[0] == True:
                return (msg[1], msg[2], msg[3])
            #create new tuple with True, and index 1-3 from original tuple
            else:
                self.__inbox.pop(i)
                newMsg = (True, msg[1], msg[2], msg[3])
                self.__inbox.insert(i, newMsg)
                return newMsg[1:]


    #delete method
    """
    Pre-condition:  Method is passed an integer.
    Post-condition:  Method checks that the integer is a valid index number. If
    valid, method pops index from class created list.

    """
    def delete(self, i):
        if i >= len(self.__inbox):
             return None
        else:
             self.__inbox.pop(i)


    #Clear method
    """
    Post-condition:  method resets the inbox to an empty list.

    """
    def clear(self):
        self.__inbox = []
```

Here's how I am using the code in my test program:

```
    #Test instantiation
    naomisInbox = SMS_store()
    martisInbox = SMS_store()

    #Test add_new_arrival
    naomisInbox.add_new_arrival("12345678912", "10:38PM", "Yay!  Sorry, been")
    martisInbox.add_new_arrival("23456789123", "10:37PM", "Hey I finally hit 90")
    martisInbox.add_new_arrival("12345678912", "10:40PM", "Now I sleep :)")
    naomisInbox.add_new_arrival("23456789123", "10:40PM", "Night")

    #Test message_count
    count = naomisInbox.message_count()
    print("Naomi has", count, "messages in her inbox.")
    count = martisInbox.message_count()
    print("Marti has", count, "messages in his inbox.\n")

    #Test get_unread_indexes
    numUnread = naomisInbox.get_unread_indexes()
    print("Naomi has unread messages at indexes: ", numUnread)
    numUnread = martisInbox.get_unread_indexes()
    print("Marti has unread messages at indexes: ", numUnread,"\n")

    #Test get_message
    msg = naomisInbox.get_message(9)
    print("Getting message from Naomi's inbox at index [9]: ")  
    if msg == None:
        print("No message at that index.")
    else:
        for item in msg:
            print(item)
    print("\n")
    numUnread = naomisInbox.get_unread_indexes()
    print("Naomi now has unread messages at indexes: ", numUnread, "\n") 
    msg = martisInbox.get_message(1)
    print("Getting message from Marti's inbox at index [1]:") 
    for item in msg:
        print(item)
    print("\n")
    numUnread = martisInbox.get_unread_indexes()
    print("Marti now has unread messages at indexes: ", numUnread, "\n")

    #Test delete
    remove = naomisInbox.delete(0)
    if remove == None:
          print("Invalid index.")
    count = naomisInbox.message_count()
    numUnread = naomisInbox.get_unread_indexes()
    print("Naomi now has", count, "messages with unread messages at index: ",\
          numUnread)


    #Test clear
    print("\nAfter clearing: ")
    naomisInbox.clear()
    count = naomisInbox.message_count()
    print("Naomi now has", count, "messages in her inbox.")
    martisInbox.clear()
    count = martisInbox.message_count()
    print("Marti now has", count, "messages in his inbox.")
```

**Error**

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/theriddler/Documents/CSIS153/Assignments/Nansen3/Nansen3.py", line 56, in <module>
    remove = naomisInbox.delete(0)
  File "/home/theriddler/Documents/CSIS153/Assignments/Nansen3/modSMS.py", line 125, in delete
NameError: global name 'msg' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated.  Sorry if it's a repeated question.  Thanks, Blackwell.

Comment: can you provide how you are using the class and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Yup, I added test code and error to original post as edit.

Comment: If that first file is modSMS.py, we are missing some lines I count 122 total lines and that isn't in the delete function.

Answer (score 0):

for your first problem.

1)if there are only two items in the list then you cannot delete the 2nd item by passing 2 as index it should be 1.

2)your second problem tells that you are using same `msg` variable in `SMS_store` class within different functions without defining it as `self` variable for the class. However cant find any thing for now. You should probably check it again as it works well on my machine.

Now a little more light on your `delete` method:

```
def delete(self, i):
    if i >= len(self.__inbox):
         return None
    else:
         self.__inbox.pop(i)
```

Here if you want to delete the last message always then just use `self.__ibox.pop()` without passing any index but in case you want to delete an indexed message then u should do `self.__ibox.pop(i-1)`

because in case `i` is last element of the list then it will always be equal to length of the list and `else` will never be executed.

Also your delete method returns `None` only in `if` condition but if `else` runs then again `None` is returned by default so

```
remove = naomisInbox.delete(0)
if remove == None:
      print("Invalid index.")
```

This will always print 'invalid index' as message even if the message gets deleted.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  I know that if there are two items in a list, the indexes are 0 and 1.  If the user enters a 2 in the delete method, 2 = len(whateverList), so it should return None, not a list index out of range error.  Shouldn't it?

As for the second issue:  Does this mean that every instance of msg I have as a variable should be listed as self.msg? 

Sorry, I'm still new to programming, so I'm sure I'm missing the obvious here.

Comment: You are correct
can you show me a case where you get `array index out of bounds` error.And as far as `global` error of msg is concerned it runs just fine on my system for all you code.

Comment: However the `else` condition in `delete` method has no return statement and if there is no return statement a python function returns `None` by default so you are returning `None` in both cases.
you can write `return self.__inbox.pop(i)` instead.

Comment: Huh...  It runs better on my terminal.  I've been running it on the Python shell.  Is it possible that that is the issue?

Comment: No it cant be...doesn't matter where you run it.
those errors must not be affected by `idle` or `terminal` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time.  I'm not sure why I'm getting the errors in Idle and not in Terminal.  I ran a number of test cases with different indexes in my delete method, and all worked as intended.  I submitted it for grading, so...hoping it was just a bizarre incident.

Comment: Yeah may be it was some problem in your code you didnt noticed and later corrected it...

Comment: @Blackwell I would suggest to avoid the headache of debugging from the terminal. User Eclipse + [pyDev](http://pydev.org)

Comment: Downloading Eclipse now.  Probably too late to do anything with the program if there's bugs, but at least I can familiarize myself with it.